# ¿Cómo definir métodos en Typescript?

Tags: typescript

Dado el siguiente código en `TypeScript`:

```
class Persona {
    constructor(public nombre: string, public apellido: string) {
    }

    nombreCompleto1 = () => {
        return this.nombre + " " + this.apellido;
    }

    nombreCompleto2() {
        return this.nombre + " " + this.apellido;
    }
}

var p = new Persona("Juan", "Pérez");

console.log(p.nombreCompleto1());
console.log(p.nombreCompleto2());
```

Como se puede ver los métodos `nombreCompleto1` y `nombreCompleto2` hacen lo mismo pero están declarados ligeramente diferente.

Al ejecutarlo en los dos casos se obtiene el resultado esperado:

```
Juan Pérez
Juan Pérez
```

¿Cuál es la diferencia entre las dos declaraciones si los dos hacen los mismo y cuál es la forma adecuada de declararlo?

Comment: Las respuestas a esta pregunta van a estar basadas en opiniones. Creo que va mas por una cuestión de gustos y legibilidad de tu código. Pero reitero, esta pregunta no corresponde en este sitio

Comment: La pregunta "_cuál es la forma adecuada de declararlo?_" se basa en opiniones.

Answer (score 0):

En cuanto a:

> ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre las dos declaraciones si los dos hacen los mismo?

La diferencia es fácilmente visible al analizar el resultado de compilar `Typescript` a `Javascript`.

```
"use strict";
class Persona {
    constructor(nombre, apellido) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.apellido = apellido;
        this.nombreCompleto1 = () => {
            return this.nombre + " " + this.apellido;
        };
    }
    nombreCompleto2() {
        return this.nombre + " " + this.apellido;
    }
}
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAKCmAnCB7AdmaBvAsAKGkOmHQgBdEBXYMlRACgAdKAjEAS2GjRQFsXE8AFzRyidmgDmAGmjM2naGEbwQHACYoRYiZICU2fEWgBffEaI9+ggMJ9GIeLQCM0ALzR6BtwD5DBYyJBMkpENGgyAAt2CAA6KwF4aABqaAAidJSI6LjlVQ0UAG4LQjM8Eu4+RLteBycUACYvf0Cgp1DwqJj4qsEsjIzUrtyVNXZNYoDS-BMgA)

Como se puede apreciar el método `nombreCompleto1` es una propiedad de la instancia y no de la clase.

En otras palabras, la definición no es heredada del constructor (*[a través del prototipo](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Herencia_y_la_cadena_de_protipos)*) sino que cada instancia tiene su propia definición lo que conlleva a:

- Mayor uso de memoria al crear instancias
- Imposibilidad de mutar dicho método en todas las instancias al mismo tipo (*puede ser malo o bueno, depende del escenario*).

#### Demo:

```js
class Persona {
    constructor(nombre, apellido) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.apellido = apellido;
        this.nombreCompleto1 = () => {
            return this.nombre + " " + this.apellido;
        };
    }
    nombreCompleto2() {
        return this.nombre + " " + this.apellido;
    }
}

console.log('Métodos definidos en la clase');
console.log('Persona.prototype.nombreCompleto1: ', Persona.prototype.nombreCompleto1);
console.log('Persona.prototype.nombreCompleto2: ', Persona.prototype.nombreCompleto2);


console.log('Mutacion de método en todas las instancias');
let p1 = new Persona("Juan", "Pérez");
let p2 = new Persona("Jhon", "Doe");
console.log(p1.nombreCompleto2());
console.log(p2.nombreCompleto2());

// Modificamos la definicion del método en el constructor
Persona.prototype.nombreCompleto2 = function() {
  return this.apellido + " " + this.nombre;
}
console.log(p1.nombreCompleto2());
console.log(p2.nombreCompleto2());
```